# Getting SOAP response in a specific order

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, annotations

I have a java file for which am receiving SOAP response. But,the response am receiving is by default alphabetical order. So,I have used a JAXB annotation like

@XmlType(propOrder={"field1","field2","field3"......"fieldn"})

Now, am receiving response in the order as I have mentioned above.

But, as I have many fields it's cumbersome to mention them all. Is there a way to get response in such a way that newly added fields comes at bottom in response without mentioning all the fields of class in annotation?

Please let me know if you need clarification on the question.

Comment: how did you solve this ?